# How to check uniqueness of email address?If its unique then insert all form values into database else show an alert?using js and jsp mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have this form.while submitting I want to check if the entered email address is unique or not.If its unique than insert fname,lname and email into database else show an alert.I want to do that using js/ajax using jsp mvc.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 
$('#Submit').click(function() {alert('in');
    var emailVal = document.getElementById("email");
            if(emailVal.value == ---){   //'---' this will come from database 
               alert("E-mail already exists.")
            }
            else{
                //redirect to ControllerServlet.java file for form submission.
             }
   
});});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pps = null;

public void dbconn() {

    try {
        String JDBC_Driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(JDBC_Driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/connectiondb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
sql = "SELECT email from user_details WHERE email = ?";
pps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pps.setString(1, ---); //i don't know what to write in place of '---'
ResultSet rs = pps.executeQuery();
%>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post">
  <p>first name:
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
  </p>
<p>last name:
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
  </p>
<p>e-mail:
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My database name is **connectiondb** and it contains the table called **user_details**.

---

user_id | email | firstname | lastname           //these 4 are the columns of table **user_details** where user_id is auto-incremented.

---

Please someone tell me how can I do that.

Comment: I wouldn't add functional code in your view like this. You're better off writing a method in a java controller and using something like jQuery ajax to call that method to do your check on email address which will return back to your view.

Comment: @mohammedkhan So, please suggest me to do that in a better way?

Comment: erm, I did lol.

Comment: @mohammedkhan okk,understood. I will try to implement that.